# ¿Como actualizar codigo javascript cada 5 segundos?

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

¿Como actualizar este codigo cada 5 segundos?. necesito que cuando el usuario cambie su huella digital, el codigo se actualice sin necesidad de actualizar la pagina, y que se cree la cookie con el valor de la nueva huella digital.

```
<center> Tu Huella Digital es: <div id="fp2"></div></center>
  <script src="fingerprint/fingerprint.js"></script>
<script>
  var fp2 = new Fingerprint({canvas: true});
  document.getElementById('fp2').innerHTML = fp2.get();
</script>
<script>
  var fn = document.getElementById('fp2').innerHTML;
  var cookieName = 'fingerprint';
  var cookieValue = fn;
  var myDate = new Date();
  myDate.setMonth(myDate.getMonth() + 12);
  document.cookie = cookieName +"=" + cookieValue + ";expires=" + myDate;
</script>
```

Comment: Hola Luis! Hacer que el código se ejecute cada X tiempo no es la forma más optima, porque el programa estaría corriendo incluso si el usuario no cambia su huella. Y si la modifica, en el peor de los casos tendría que esperar hasta 5 segundos para ver los cambios reflejados en la aplicación. Lo que te recomiendo hacer es crear un listener que este escuchando al evento "onChange" de la huella y que ejecute una función (callback) cada vez que hay un cambio.

Answer (score 1):

en Javasctipt hay un metodo para lanzar una funcion cada x tiempo. Se llama setInterval(), que recibe dos parámetros; primero la funcion que deseas que se ejecute periodicamente, y segundo el tiempo en milisegundos cada cuanto quieres ejecutarla. En tu caso 5.000 milisegundos.
La sintaxis es asi:

setInterval ('tuFuncion()', 5000);

Espero te sirva para lo que estas buscando.